# Find parameters of a class by the class name

Tags: scala, generics, scala-macros, variance, scala-reflect

I am working on a macro annotation, and I have something like this:

```
def findClass(className: String) : ClassSymbol = {
  val tree = c.typecheck(c.parse(s"??? : ${className}"));
  return tree.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass;
}
```

The issue is that when `className` is something like `List`, it obviously complains because it expects parameters. If it is `List[String]`, then it is fine.

To be honest, I do not fully understand why, for example, `classOf[List]` is not accepted considering that the generic type in the List is invariant? Doing `classOf[List[String]]` and `classOf[List[Integer]]`, returns the same class.

So, assuming that my method `findClass` will always receive a class without parameters, or with invariant parameters, how can I typecheck the `ValDef`?

Answer (score 0):

> why, for example, classOf[List] is not accepted considering that the generic type in the List is invariant

Because the correct way to write this is `classOf[List[_]]`, for consistency with other usages. The variance of parameters doesn't matter (though `List` is covariant, not invariant).

This is ugly, and there are probably better solutions I am failing to think of, but you could try typechecking `s"??? : ${className}"`, then `s"??? : ${className}[_]"`, etc.

Comment: yes, at the moment that is how I have done this, but try and error is very ugly. There must be a better solution, perhaps with extractors or lambda type functions. But cant think on any either.